# What is meant by infinitely many circular arrangements of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the 4th paragraph on page #1 of the introductory Algebra book, ["Numbers and Symmetry: An Introduction to Algebra" by Bernard L. Johnston & Fred Richman](https://books.google.com/books?id=koUfrlgsmUcC&pg=PA1&dq=%22numbers+and+symmetry%22+richman+%22infinitely+many+circular+versions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwickP6yrMfXAhVH2yYKHTkFD84Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22numbers%20and%20symmetry%22%20richman%20%22infinitely%20many%20circular%20versions%22&f=false), it is stated that equally spaced arrangements of points, representing integers, can be arranged in a circular way in infinitely many ways.  It is stated that "it turns out" that this is the case, but no references are provided, and this claim is neither proven nor demonstrated to be true.

I'm confused about what this means...

1) I understand that there are an infinite number of circles (each with a varying radius), and I can visualize each as having an **infinite** number of equally spaced points arranged along its circumference by imagining successive "partitions" of the circumference into equal arcs where the length of each arc is reduced "ad infinitum"...and the endpoints of these arc will the the points representing the "mapping" of the **entire set of integers**.    And since there are an infinite number of circles onto which such an arrangement can be made, it follows that there are in infinite number of such arrangements of the integers on a circle.

Is this what the authors meant?

Is my thinking above mathematically correct?

2) But there is clearly a difference between arranging the integers on an **infinite** straight line versus arranging them on a **finite** circle, since one is infinite and the other is finite, no?  It seems that on an infinite straight line, it need not be so "densely" packed.  But this line of thinking seems to be heading a bit towards the Zeno paradox, though that is not my concern; my confusion is that, though there are an infinite number of such circles, any one arrangement of the **entire set of integers** is still "congruent" to that of any other circle with a different radius. No?  If so, then the arrangement is still of the same form...  Like the construct of a cup with a standard shape -- it doesn't matter how big a cup I make by scaling it larger or smaller, it is still of the same "form" as the original, so *why should we count it as a different arrangement?*  Likewise, even on the number line, in one dimension, though the unit spacing may vary, all such arrangements are still of the same "form" and vary only by a scaling factor, no?

So my understanding is that there is only **one** such arrangement of the **"contiguous/ordered"** set of integers on the number line, but likewise, there is just **one** arrangement of the entire set of integers on **any** circle.  No?

Thanks in advance for your kind reply!

Answer (score 0):

He refers to the quotient $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ as "circular numbers". What he means by circular is that when you continue to add the elements therein, you just go round and round like the hands of the clock.

With this in mind, the meaning of "infinitely many circular versions [of the integers]" is that there is such a quotient for any natural number $n$, and the natural numbers are infinitely many.

The various "circular numbers" are algebraic objects, or if you wish, a setting or space in which you can do usual arithmetic. They aren't circles in any strict sense, so your geometrical considerations are not really applicable.

If you want to see the integers as a space, it would be a *discrete* space. This means that they consist of points that are isolated from each other. You can see the various "circular numbers" as circles of various radii, but since you can't really define a "size" in any interesting way, you might as well not bother.

Comment: Dear Neptun, thanks for your reply!  It is a useful abstract interpretation.  But I was really hoping for an elementary geometric explanation since the authors are encouraging such a route in this introduction when they state (in the previous paragraph) "we can construct new integers by thinking geometrically."

Comment: @TeslaPenrose You could think about the clock. Does adding more hours to the day make the face of the clock bigger or smaller? Answer: you can make it any size you want because it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you read carefully you will see that they write "the ordinary integers can be thought of as equally spaced points on the number line" and then proceeds to present the Gaussian integers as a 2D analogue, and the finite rings $\mathbb Z/n$ as "circular" analogues of this idea. There isn't really anything more to the geometric aspect in the book as far as I can see..

Comment: Ahh...yes.  You are right.  My mistake was that I understood it as "infinitely many such arrangements" whereas what is meant is "infinitely many such [circular] integers".   Thank you Neptun!!!